# Typing in other language (hebrew) is not working on android 2.3.x in a textarea

Tags: android, html, textarea, hebrew

I have a html5 mobile app with a textarea on it.
When typing english letters I can see the letters in the textarea and when changing the language to hebrew, I continue to type but no letters are displayed on the textarea.

This happens only on android 2.3.x.

Has any one encountered the problem?

Thanks,
Doron